# GPIO17 only works after calling 'GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN)'

Tags: gpio, shutdown

I have a fresh installed RaspberryPi running `Raspberry PI OS Lite (32-bit)` from 2020-12-02 with a mounted OnOff-Shim. Starting the Raspberry via button works fine, but the shutdown sequence is not executed. After some tinkering, I noticed that it suddenly works after calling the following python script.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN)
```

This sadly only works once, so after booting again, the shutdown skript is again not called. I then added `gpio=17=ip` to */boot/config.txt* - without success.

Using `pi@raspberrypi:~ $ raspi-gpio get 17` I observed the following:

Before calling the script:

- Button not pressed:

> GPIO 17: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT

- Button pressed (same result):

> GPIO 17: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT

After calling the script:

- Button not pressed:

> GPIO 17: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT

- Button pressed (same result):

> GPIO 17: level=**0** fsel=0 func=INPUT
> Broadcast message from root@raspberrypi (somewhere) (Sat Dec  5 19:46:12 2020):
> BCM 17 held low, system shutdown in 0 minutes
> Connection to phoniebox closed by remote host.
> Connection to phoniebox closed.

What can I do to have the OnOff-Shims shutdown-script be executed correctly from the start?

### Update:

I'm now calling the mentioned python script in */etc/rc.local*, which works but feels totally wrong...

Comment: How did you install the Pimoroni script?

Comment: I used the one-liner from the [website](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/onoff-shim): `curl https://get.pimoroni.com/onoffshim | bash `

Comment: The Python makes no difference.  You must be doing something else which makes a difference.

Comment: Running the script makes all the difference. I can actually press the button while executing the last line `GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN)` and immediatly see the message and watch the RaspberryPi shut down.

Comment: Can you check if *disable_cleanshutd=1* is in /boot/config.txt also would be worth seeing if `raspi-gpio get` returns anything odd for pin.  See if daemon is running (cleanshutd) and what params in /etc/cleanshutd.conf - it feels like pin 4 and pin 17 mixed up (the two pins used by shims for power)